# Is it possible to programmatically add items to global contextual menus?

Tags: swift, macos, contextmenu

New to OS X development, wondering if its possible to add my programs menu item to any contextual menu throughout the system when text is selected. It seems it is possible to do in Safari extensions, but wondering if there's a system-wide API for this?

Comment: I don't know if this helps but have you seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface?language=objc) Sample project? It's for the new Mac Catalyst

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add such items. It's not done dynamically at run time. It's a static property of your app.

The functionality is referred to as [Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html). That documentation is "legacy" but still valid. It's in Objective-C, so you'll have to translate to Swift.

See also System Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services (in the left-hand column) for where/how users configure Services.